# How to load external url to cordova webview - iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

Want to how to call an external url in embedded cordova webview in iOS application. Can we escape from giving www folder and start page?

example url: http://www.stackoverflow.com

This is the snippet i tried, but since that checks for the www folder, this wont work.

```
CDVViewController *viewController = [CDVViewController new];
viewController.wwwFolderName = @"";
viewController.startPage = @"http://www.stackoverflow.com";
viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
```

is there a way to call such external url from this end?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the task :

[viewController.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"]]];